# Camel Timer executing method twice

Tags: apache-camel

I'm trying to make timer using camel to execute some method in bean every 5 sec for example.

I defined in camel context timer route :

```
<camel:route id="PERGING-sent">
            <from uri="timer://foo?fixedRate=true&amp;period=5000"/>
            <to uri="bean:purger?method=purge"/>
            <to uri="mock:result"/> 
</camel:route>
```

the problem in that every 5 sec this method is executing twice ! 
Very odd...
What can I do to prevent this from happening ?

Comment: what version of camel are you using?

Comment: How about some log snippets as well =)

Comment: There is nothing special about the log except the evidence of my bean executing twice . it is like it comes from 2 different threads. I have only one timer reference in camel context.

Comment: some trace level logs would show us threading and such. It's difficult to give insight with so little info as this is not a common issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the Problem.
some were in the code I call twice to :

```
context = new `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("MyCamelContext.xml")`
```

so the routing is creating twice , so is the timer.